# Coldfusion Session/Application Scope Empty After Calling Websockets WSPublish()

Tags: coldfusion

I am experiencing a weird behavior with the application/session scope in Coldfusion (2016 UPDATE 5) when using Websockets and calling WSPublish.

Below is code that illustrates this anomaly:

```
<cfdump var="#application.Security.GetSession()#" label="1A application.Security.GetSession()">
<cfdump var="#session#" label="1B session">

<cfset wsPublish("notifications", "Test") />

<cfdump var="#application.Security.GetSession()#" label="2A application.Security.GetSession()">
<cfdump var="#session#" label="2B session">
```

In 1A and 1B, the session is returned as expcted.

Then I run the WSPublish() function.

In 2A, the session is empty, but in 2B it is still there as before.

So, after running WSPublish(), when I try and access the session by calling another CFC to retrieve it (2A), it does not exist. However, the session does exist when accessing it directly (2B).

All the application.Security.GetSession() method does is this:

```
<cfcomponent output="no">
    <cffunction name="GetSession" returntype="any">
        <cfif NOT IsDefined("session")>
            <cfreturn StructNew() />
        <cfelse>
            <cfreturn session />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

If I remove the WSPublish() call, then 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B all return the correct session data.

Why is WSPublish() causing this anomaly and how do I resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `GetSession` to begin with? You could just pass the `session` scope to the mentioned other CFC. Last time I checked, sessionManagement will always maintain a session scope (will create session if not referenced in request), so there's no need to check if it's defined.

Comment: @Alex: While technically you are correct, your objection is irrelevant to the overall issue. This is a simplified version of a bigger issue. 

The GetSession call in this example is an ilustrative example for another call "GetSessionUser()". 

And no, sessionManagement is not maintaining a session scope - if it did, I wouldn't have to do the IsDefined () check like is currently being done.

I am trying to understand why the session does not exist in a certain context, so hopefully we can stick to that please.